# Incorrect syntax near ')'. how can I fix it?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

```sql
SELECT
    obj.obj_id obj_id,
    obj.obj_nm obj_nm,
    objsecu.usr_id usr_id,
    objsecu.email_id email_id,
    dbo.NVL(objprop.prop_val,'MM/DD/YYYY') prop_val
FROM
    od_mdv_actual_obj obj,
    od_md_objsecu objsecu,
    od_mdv_objprop objprop
WHERE
    obj.obj_id = objsecu.obj_id
    AND   obj.clnt_id = objsecu.clnt_id
    AND   obj.proj_id = objsecu.proj_id
    AND   obj.schm_id = objsecu.schm_id
    AND   obj.obj_id = objprop.obj_id (+)
    AND   obj.clnt_id = objprop.clnt_id (+)
    AND   obj.proj_id = objprop.proj_id (+)
    AND   obj.schm_id = objprop.schm_id (+)
    AND   2007 = objprop.prop_id (+)
    AND   obj.clnt_id =1
    AND   obj.proj_id =1
    AND   obj.schm_id =1
    AND   obj.obj_id IN (
        SELECT
            obj_depn_id
        FROM
            od_md_objrel
        WHERE
            rel_typ_id = 19
            AND   clnt_id =1
            AND   proj_id =1
            AND   schm_id =1
    );
```

I am trying to fetch user list using the above query dbo.NVL failing and showing error as "Incorrect syntax near ')'. " How to fix it? Please help me

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the Error because of the (+) symbols.

```
AND   obj.obj_id = objprop.obj_id (+)
AND   obj.clnt_id = objprop.clnt_id (+)
AND   obj.proj_id = objprop.proj_id (+)
AND   obj.schm_id = objprop.schm_id (+)
AND   2007 = objprop.prop_id (+)
```

Remove that `(+)`, and it will work fine.

Comment: I need to do left outer join

Comment: then use the Left join. There is No Syntax for Join using (+) symbol in SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

As per the comment , you are looking to Left join..

```
SELECT
    obj.obj_id obj_id,
    obj.obj_nm obj_nm,
    objsecu.usr_id usr_id,
    objsecu.email_id email_id,
    dbo.NVL(objprop.prop_val,'MM/DD/YYYY') prop_val
FROM od_mdv_actual_obj obj 
    left join od_md_objsecu objsecu on   obj.obj_id = objsecu.obj_id
        AND   obj.clnt_id = objsecu.clnt_id
        AND   obj.proj_id = objsecu.proj_id
        AND   obj.schm_id = objsecu.schm_id
    left join od_mdv_objprop objprop on   obj.obj_id = objprop.obj_id  
        AND   obj.clnt_id = objprop.clnt_id 
        AND   obj.proj_id = objprop.proj_id 
        AND   obj.schm_id = objprop.schm_id 
WHERE   objprop.prop_id =2007 
    AND   obj.clnt_id =1
    AND   obj.proj_id =1
    AND   obj.schm_id =1
    AND   obj.obj_id IN (
        SELECT
            obj_depn_id
        FROM
            od_md_objrel
        WHERE
            rel_typ_id = 19
            AND   clnt_id =1
            AND   proj_id =1
            AND   schm_id =1
    );
```